# SQL Server Select Statements with Multiple Rowcounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Is there a way to call column from one table and sort   by a date from another table and does this for three numbers 5,6,99? i have an example that may clarify. This is an interesting procedure that we are currently stuck on at a plant.

---this is example tables of what it is ----

table a

```
6                queued  (there are ten of these with ID's of course)
5                queued  (there are 8 with id's )
99               queued  (there are 7 with id's)
```

****Table B example of what it is********

table b

(the exact qty doesnt match, its an example. Where there is an ID in table A; Table B has an ID matching to equal each other. )

```
id   11/1/2013  10:00:01
id   11/1/2013  10:00:02
id   11/1/2013  10:00:03
id   11/1/2013  10:00:04
id   11/1/2013  10:00:05
id   11/1/2013  10:00:06
id   11/1/2013  10:00:07
id   11/1/2013  10:00:08
id   11/1/2013  10:00:09
id   11/1/2013  10:00:10
id   11/1/2013  10:00:11
id   11/1/2013  10:00:12
id   11/1/2013  10:00:13
id   11/1/2013  10:00:14
id   11/1/2013  10:00:15
id   11/1/2013  10:00:16
id   11/1/2013  10:00:17
id   11/1/2013  10:00:18
id   11/1/2013  10:00:19
id   11/1/2013  10:00:20
```

****The form of what it should be NOTE* I am displaying the date to show you the order, but in reality the time does not appear its behind the scenes************

Form

```
 6 id  11/1/2013  10:00:05
 6 id  11/1/2013  10:00:06
 6 id  11/1/2013  10:00:07
 6 id  11/1/2013  10:00:08
 6 id  11/1/2013  10:00:09
 6 id  11/1/2013  10:00:10
 5 id  11/1/2013  10:00:02
 5 id  11/1/2013  10:00:03
 5 id  11/1/2013  10:00:04
 5 id  11/1/2013  10:00:11
 5 id  11/1/2013  10:00:13
 5 id  11/1/2013  10:00:17
99 id  11/1/2013  10:00:01
99 id  11/1/2013  10:00:12
99 id  11/1/2013  10:00:14
99 id  11/1/2013  10:00:15
99 id  11/1/2013  10:00:16
99 id  11/1/2013  10:00:18
```

The VB doesnt need to be changed. It works in other procedures and is happy running as it should. I just need the right order to appear in the form. Does anyone know how to do this?

SQL:

```
   ALTER PROC [Controls].[spBatch]
       @Status varchar output
      ,@RoasterNumber int output
      ,@RoastProfile int output
      ,@ChargeWeight float output
      ,@SuperSackID int output
   AS
   SET NOCOUNT ON

   DECLARE @RETURN int


select  Top 6 *  
from wip.RoasterQueueSequence RQS 
inner join wip.schedule s on s.fk_roasterqueuesequenceid =           RQS.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID 
where 
   rqs.Status = 'Queued' 
   and rqs.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID = s.FK_RoasterQueueSequenceID 
   and rqs.RoasterNumber = 6
   order by 
   s.publishedstartdatetime asc

  SELECT @RETURN = @@rowcount 
  FROM WIP.RoasterQueueSequence 
  WHERE  Roasternumber = 6

  select Top 6 *  
  from wip.RoasterQueueSequence RQS 
  inner join wip.schedule s on s.fk_roasterqueuesequenceid = RQS.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID 
  where 
  rqs.Status = 'Queued'   
  and rqs.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID = s.FK_RoasterQueueSequenceID 
  and rqs.RoasterNumber = 5
  order by 
  s.publishedstartdatetime asc

  SELECT @RETURN2 = @@rowcount 
  FROM WIP.RoasterQueueSequence 
  WHERE  Roasternumber = 5

   select  Top 6 *  
   from wip.RoasterQueueSequence RQS 
   inner join wip.schedule s on s.fk_roasterqueuesequenceid =     RQS.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID 
  where 
   rqs.Status = 'Queued' 
   and rqs.PK_RoasterQueueSequenceID = s.FK_RoasterQueueSequenceID 
   and rqs.RoasterNumber = 99
   order by 
   s.publishedstartdatetime asc

  SELECT @RETURN3 = @@rowcount 
  FROM WIP.RoasterQueueSequence 
  WHERE  Roasternumber = 99


 set @TotalRows = @RETURN + @RETURN2 + @RETURN3

 --set @TotalRows = @@rowcount
 return @TotalRows
```

Comment: Maybe you should find a more precise topic. 'Sql Server and vb' is very general.

Comment: You need to actually ask a question.

Comment: Could you edit your question to clarify what the problem actually is? Are you trying to say "intDataRowMO" variable has the wrong number?

Comment: It seems that your SQL already does what you are asking for...

Comment: It seems as the procedure doesnt succuessfully recgnoize the row count in vb. There are so many rowcounts how do i make it into one rowcount that incorporate 6  of each (6,5,99) for a total of 18?

Comment: VB is only seeing roasternumber 6. How is this possible when i set all RETURNS equal to a totalrowcount and returned that values. I debugged it and i have 18 rows but individually( 6 of each). I need all rowcounts? Can this be done without mixing up eachother based of the datetime?